Local androidStudio test are not being executed at all in browserStack app automate espresso
I have configured the BS app automate espresso with AndroidStudio, builds are visible to bs dashboard.
However, my android tests are not being executed when I start a new build command and the status for them is always failed ( even if when running them manually through androidStudio, the status is passed) , command example :
curl -u "< username >:< password >"
-X POST "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/espresso/v2/build"
-d '{"app": "bs://<app_id>", "testSuite": "bs://<test_suite_id>", "devices": ["Google Pixel-8.0"], "coverage": true, "debugscreenshots": true, "project": "<project_name>", "class": ["<class_name_of_the_test>"]}'
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```,
do I need to add some capabilities to my android tests ? Or should I enable the local testing in BS ? if so, do I need to add some setup for local testing to the android tests ?

many thanks in advance ,
mary

note : I have enabled the local testing via terminal using 

./BrowserStackLocal --key 
the status is success every time . But after running the test from android studio ( status test is passed) and doing manually the BS build command from terminal, status test is failed and Duration is 0.0s ... I think that the test is not really executed

